# Angular 6 Router - children routing doesn't work

Tags: typescript, routes, angular6, router, children

I have a main router as follow:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: "login",
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './modules/login/login.module#LoginModule',
    }
}
```

whitch routes well the root domain into my login module.

into LoginModule I have another router (login.routes), structured in this way:

```
export const router: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: LoginPanelComponent,
                outlet: 'login'
            },
            {
                path:'change_password',
                component: ChangePasswordPanelComponent,
                outlet: 'login'
            }
       ]
    }
}
```

into login.component.html I have a secondary router-outlet named 'login'

```
<div class="login-component-wrapper">
    <router-outlet name="login"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

now:

when i call root domanin (www.mysite.com) router works well, browser is redirected into `www.mysite.com/login` and it is called LoginPanelComponent page, but if I call `www.mysite.com/login/change_password` i receive a "page not found" from router.

I've found a solution but I think is not so clean

```
export const router: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: LoginPanelComponent,
                outlet: 'login'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'change_password',
        component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path:'',
                component: ChangePasswordPanelComponent,
                outlet: 'login'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

in this way routing works well but I think it isn't the best solution, it has a rendundant part (LoginComponent part)

there is another way, like the no working first example to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Your route ordering is messed up and the router doesn't have a chance to resolve the URL:

Base routes

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './modules/login/login.module#LoginModule',
    },
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: "login",
    }
}
```

Login Routes

```
export const router: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path:'change_password',
                component: ChangePasswordPanelComponent,
                outlet: 'login'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                component: LoginPanelComponent,
                outlet: 'login'
            }
       ]
    }
}
```